# Cant connect to mssql database using sqlsrv inside php class method

Tags: php, sql-server

Please help I have been kicking my head against walls for hours trying to query mssql database inside a php class method. Using procedural method I can query and display the results but in php class i get a status 500 (internal server error) anytime I include connection file. Here is my code.

**student class**

```
  <?php class Student{
  var $name;

  function setName($item){
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/eazycal/con_string.php'); 
    $sql="SELECT * FROM Students WHERE StdID='".$item."'";
    $stmt=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql); 
    $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
    $this->name = $row['Surame'];
  }

  function getName(){
     return $this->title;
  }
}
?>
```

**Database connection file**

```
<?php
$serverName="localhost\DBSERVER";
$connectionInfo=array( "Database"=>"school","UID"=>"John","PWD"=>"love");
$conn=sqlsrv_connect( $serverName,$connectionInfo);
?>
```

**implementation**

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']'/classes/stdClass.php'); 
$entity = new Student;
$entity->setName( "34" );
$student=$entity->getName();
$resp=array('name'=>$student);
echo json_encode($resp);
```

Comment: Please this is an issue with OOP I don't, if i remove the connection file the page loads alright

Comment: and besides there is no log information in the file. Php error reporting is turned on